# `Property 'alive' does not exist` on app compile

Tags: javascript, angular

When I try to run my angular app, I am getting error as :

```
ERROR in src/app/new-card-input/new-card-input.component.ts(25,24): error TS2339: Property 'alive' does not exist on type 'NewCardInputComponent'.
```

what is the issue here?

here is my code :

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Output, HostListener, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {NgForm, FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import { takeWhile, debounceTime, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-new-card-input',
    templateUrl: './new-card-input.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./new-card-input.component.scss'],
    host: {'class': 'col-4'}
})
export class NewCardInputComponent implements OnInit {

    newCardForm: FormGroup;
    @ViewChild('form') public form:NgForm;

    constructor(fb:FormBuilder) {
        this.newCardForm = fb.group({
            'text': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)])],
        });

        this.newCardForm.valueChanges.pipe(
        filter((value) => this.newCardForm.valid),
        debounceTime(500),
        takeWhile(() => this.alive)
        ).subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data);
        });
    }

    public newCard:any = {text:''}

    @Output() onCardAdd = new EventEmitter<string>();

    @HostListener('document:keypress', ['$event'])
    handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
        if (event.code === "Enter" && this.newCardForm.valid) {
            this.addCard(this.newCardForm.controls['text'].value);
        }
    }

    addCard(text) {
        this.onCardAdd.emit(text);
        this.newCardForm.controls['text'].setValue('');
    }



    ngOnInit() {}

}
```

any one help me?

Comment: your are calling this.alive but alive is not previously declared.

Comment: how to declare that? I thought that's from `rxjs` ..is it not?

Comment: no, it's a local scope property. You could add it above newCardForm: FormGroup; Just add the following alive; and the error will go away, though looking at the code you may get other errors...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define `private alive = true;` Here is current step of the code of the tutorial you are following. [Getting started with angular 5.](https://github.com/bopm/getting-started-ng5/blob/04bae11790e9a7f2f6c15be307542b88509a640d/src/app/new-card-input/new-card-input.component.ts)

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Output, HostListener, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {NgForm, FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import { takeWhile, debounceTime, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-new-card-input',
    templateUrl: './new-card-input.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./new-card-input.component.scss'],
    host: {'class': 'col-4'}
})
export class NewCardInputComponent implements OnInit {

    newCardForm: FormGroup;
    private alive = true;
    @ViewChild('form') public form:NgForm;

    constructor(fb:FormBuilder) {
        this.newCardForm = fb.group({
            'text': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)])],
        });

        this.newCardForm.valueChanges.pipe(
        filter((value) => this.newCardForm.valid),
        debounceTime(500),
        takeWhile(() => this.alive)
        ).subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data);
        });
    }

    public newCard:any = {text:''}

    @Output() onCardAdd = new EventEmitter<string>();

    @HostListener('document:keypress', ['$event'])
    handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
        if (event.code === "Enter" && this.newCardForm.valid) {
            this.addCard(this.newCardForm.controls['text'].value);
        }
    }

    addCard(text) {
        this.onCardAdd.emit(text);
        this.newCardForm.controls['text'].setValue('');
    }



    ngOnInit() {}

}
```